# Android application doesn't run with AdMob

Tags: android, android-layout

I have problem with AdMob in my Android application. I have done exactly everything described [here](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals#android), but when I start the program, it doesn't run (there are a lot of bugs). I will show you a fragment of program:

```
public class MenuMainActivity extends Activity{

private AdView adView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu_main);  

    adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "(code-15 signs)");
    RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.layout.activity_menu_main);
    layout.addView(adView);
    adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
```

And also xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/titleOfGame"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="3dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:text="@string/title_of_game_text" />
```

...

When I comments two lines:

```
//layout.addView(adView);
//adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
```

Everything is ok. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you use findViewById() you must pass an id, there you are passing a "layout".

should be something like:

```
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.adLayer);
```

create a Layout with "adLayer" as the "id" and position it in your layout where you like the Ads to show up.

Comment: When I creating a layout I don`t know how to add any Id because there is only: layout_height, layout_width, tools by default after creating. Dynamically adding Id`s to <resources> in res/values/ids.xml is also bad idea in my case. I don`t know how to:
" create a Layout with "adLayer" as the "id" "?

Comment: Just add an id tag to your layout android:id="@+id/myLayoutName"

Answer (score 0):

As the previous posters have mentioned you need to create a specific place in your layout where you want yout advert to appear, for example, using your supplied code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/titleOfGame"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="3dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:text="@string/title_of_game_text"/>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/adLayer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    etc.   etc./>
```

You then need to change the code in your activity to :

```
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.adLayer);
```

as BrainCrash suggested. 
Hope this helps!

Comment: Good idea but it still not working. I have add what you wrote but it still the same problem. "R.java" file adds "adLayer" in class "id" and everything is ok. But when I starting the program there are bugs. I have add jars of course and also override "onDestroy()". Without advertisements everything is ok.

Comment: Have you tried specifying your advert as a view in your XML file rather than a layout? I have found this to be quiet straightforward. There is a good example here: http://jmsliu.com/209

Comment: I have copied:
 - GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.2.1
 - libGoogleAnalyticsV2
two downloaded files to folder "libs" in Eclipse in project.
In activity_main.xml I have added "android:id="@+id/mainLayout".
In manifest I have added:
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
and
 <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
and everything is ok. Thank you.